# Maven exec fails to write results to output directory

Tags: java, maven

I have the below configuration in pom.xml to bundle all the Maven dependencies in one jar. When I run the `mvn exec` command, it is working fine except it doesn't write the results to an output directory that I have configured to store the results when my main method is called.

If I run the same program from command line and pass the arguments, the output directory has the results, but it doesn't work from Maven. What am I missing?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>com.myapp.test.AppLauncher</argument>
                        <argument>-a</argument>
                        <argument>${Param1}</argument>
                        <argument>-b</argument>
                        <argument>${Param2}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Here is the result of the maven command -

```
$mvn exec:exec -DParam1=DefaultMode -DParam2=Test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myApp
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (default-cli) @ myApp ---
Fetching results from database
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.943 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-11T21:56:30-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If what you really are trying to accomplish is "bundle all the maven dependencies in one jar" then I would suggest you look at maven-shade-plugin. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Agreed, but there has to be a solution to this using mvn exec as well. I have also tried adding the output directory within configuration in my pom, but no luck. <outputDirectory>output/</outputDirectory>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What does you programm Applauncher exactly do? Should it write something into a particular folder? Or do you expect the exec-maven-plugin to write something to a particular location?

Comment: App launcher basically reads data from input folders, processes them, and writes to output directory. I just want to be able to write to the output directory when I run mvn exec:exec. If I run the program in eclipse, it writes to the directory, but it doesn't work from Maven.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<configuration>` element, include something like `<workingDirectory>target/output</workingDirectory>`. [Here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing destination directory explicitly and its worth adding execution phase as well. The maven plugin configuration is as follows.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath/>
                        <argument>com.kp.deployment.CopyResourceFiles</argument>
                        <argument>destinationDirectory=${project.build.directory}</argument>
                        <argument>param1=${param1}</argument>
                        <argument>param2=${param2}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And the hava class is as follows

```
public class CopyResourceFiles {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        String destionDir = "";
        String param1 ="";
        String Param2 ="";
        for(String str : args){

            if(str != null && str.contains("destinationDirectory=")){
                destionDir = str.substring(str.indexOf("=")+1, str.length());
            }
            if(str != null && str.contains("param1=")){
                param1 = str.substring(str.indexOf("=")+1, str.length());
            }
            if(str != null && str.contains("param2=")){
                Param2 = str.substring(str.indexOf("=")+1, str.length());
            }
        }
        destionDir+="/kpfile.txt";

        List<String> contents= new ArrayList<String>();
        contents.add(param1);
        contents.add(Param2);
        FileUtils.writeLines(new File(destionDir), contents);

        System.out.println("Sucessfully written");

    }

}
```